# Integrating WCF Client and ASMX WSE 3.0 Service

Tags: wcf, integration, wse

I almost regret that I even *started* programming.

How do I integrate those two enterprisey beasts? More specifically, I have a third-party ASMX service which uses WSE 3.0 (authentication & message signing). Now in following with "best" Microsoft practices and `svcutil` a WCF proxy to this service. For some obscure reason (I believe I even read somewhere on the Internets that this is actually by design), `svcutil` does not import this extra security configuration added by WSE. All samples available on the net are either outdated or do not compile or produce configuration errors.

Is there any chance of integrating these two technologies?

Comment: If you don't have WSDL which includes WS-Policies for WS-Security, ask them to provide sample of valid SOAP request and response. We can try to define your WCF binding from that examples.

Answer (score 0):

I believe, that svcutil does not generate proxy, since 3rd party company has blocked it from security reasons, which is correct. I am sure you can ask them to generate proxy on their machines using svcutils and send you their code.

Good luck!